# ¿Como eliminar elementos repetidos es una Pila?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Me mandaron a hacer una Pila en c++, está prácticamente lista, pero tengo el problema que cuando añado más elementos (tipo int) a la pila a la hora de mostrar la pila me muestra 3 veces el mismo elementos (algo que no se quiere).

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream.h>

int resp =0, x, op, cont=0;

struct nodo{
    int nro;
    struct nodo *sgte;
};

typedef struct nodo *Puntero;

class Pila{
    public:
        Pila(void);
        void Apilar(int );
        int Desapilar(void );
        void Cima(void);
        bool PilaVacia(void);
        void MostrarPila(void);
        void DestruirPila(void);

    private:
        Puntero cima;

};
Pila::Pila(void){
    cima=NULL;
}

bool Pila::PilaVacia(void){
    if(cima==NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Pila::Apilar(int x){
    Puntero p_aux;
    p_aux=new(struct nodo);
    p_aux->nro=x;
    p_aux->sgte=cima;
    cima=p_aux;

}

void Pila::Cima(){
    int x;
    if(cima==NULL)
        cout<<"\n\n\tPila Vacia...!";

    else {
        x=cima->nro;
        cout<<"\n\tLa Cima es :"<<x<<endl;
    }
}

int Pila::Desapilar(void){
    int x;
    Puntero p_aux;
    if(cima==NULL)
        cout<<"\n\n\tPila Vacia...!!";
    else{
        p_aux=cima;
        x=p_aux->nro;
        cima=cima->sgte;
        delete(p_aux);
    }
    return x;
}

void Pila::MostrarPila(void){
    Puntero p_aux;
    p_aux=cima;

    while(p_aux!=NULL){
        cout<<"\t "<<p_aux->nro<<endl;
        p_aux=p_aux->sgte;
    }
}

void Pila::DestruirPila(void){
    Puntero p_aux;

    while(cima!=NULL){
            p_aux=cima;
            cima=cima->sgte;
            delete(p_aux);
    }

}
void menu(void)
{

   void menu(void)
{

    printf(" MENU DE LA PILA\n");
    printf("1. INSERTAR\n");
    printf("2. SACAR PILA\n");
    printf("3. MOSTRAR\n");
    printf("4. MOSTRAR ESTADO DE LA PILA\n");
    printf("5. SALIR\n");
    printf("QUE DESEA REALIZAR\n");

}

int main(void ){
    system("color 0a");
    hoja(); getch();  system("cls");
    Pila pila;


    do
    {
        menu();  cin>> op;

        switch(op)
        {


            case 1:
                    printf("Ingrese elementos a la pila: ");
                    scanf("%d", &x);
                    pila.Apilar(x);
               printf("\nSu numero apilado es %d", x);

                        do{
                    pila.Apilar(x);
                            printf("\nUsted desea apilar alguun otro número? [SI = 0] [NO =1]");
                            scanf("%d",&resp);

                            if(resp==0){
                                pila.Apilar(x);
                                printf("\nIngrese elementos");
                                scanf("%d",&x);
                            }
                            else
                                printf("\Carga de pila exitosa");
                        }while(resp==0);

                break;
            case 2:
                    if(pila.PilaVacia()==true)
                        cout<<"\n\n\tPila Vacia....";
                    else{
                        x = pila.Desapilar( );
                        cout<<"\n\n\tNumero "<<x<<" desapilado\n";
                        }
            break;


            case 3:
                    cout << "\n\n\t MOSTRANDO PILA\n\n";
                    if(pila.PilaVacia()!=true)
                        pila.MostrarPila(  );
                    else
                        cout<<"\n\n\tPila vacia..!"<<endl;
                    break;


            case 4:
                   pila.DestruirPila(  );
                    cout<<"\n\n\t\tPila eliminada...\n\n";
                    break;

            case 5:
                cout << "\n\n\t MOSTRANDO CIMA\n\n";
                    if(pila.PilaVacia()!=true)
                        pila.Cima(  );
                    else
                        cout<<"\n\n\tPila vacia..!"<<endl;
                    break;
                case 6:
                        return 0;
            break;

            default:
            cout<<"\n\n\t\tIntrduzca una opcion valida\n\n";

            break;
         }//sw

        cout<<endl<<endl;
        system("pause");  system("cls");

    }while(op!=6);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maria bienvenida a [es.so]. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que nos muestres el código que causa el problema, o un [mcve], para poder ver donde está el problema y la causa de la impresión errónea, si no es imposible ya que las causas pueden ser múltiples. Por favor usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/109763/edit) y añade el código a la pregunta, para formatearlo lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor. un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué datos de entrada pones?

Answer (score 2):

> a la hora de mostrar la pila me muestra 3 veces el mismo elementos

```
case 1:
  printf("Ingrese elementos a la pila: ");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  pila.Apilar(x); // 1
  printf("\nSu numero apilado es %d", x);

  do{ // 2
    pila.Apilar(x); // 3
    printf("\nUsted desea apilar alguun otro número? [SI = 0] [NO =1]");
    scanf("%d",&resp);

    if(resp==0){
      pila.Apilar(x); // 4
      printf("\nIngrese elementos");
      scanf("%d",&x);
    }
    else
      printf("\Carga de pila exitosa");
  }while(resp==0);

  break;
```

Supongamos que el usuario quiere añadir una serie de elementos a la lista:

- Se le pide un número (llamémoslo X)
- en (1) se añade X a la pila
- (2) es un do-while, luego **siempre**  se ejecuta al menos una vez
- en (3)  se añade X a la pila (otra vez)
- el usuario responde con un 0 (quiere añadir más números)
- en (4)  se añade X a la pila (otra vez y van 3)

Como ves, el bucle no tiene absolutamente ningún sentido. En el ejercicio te están pidiendo una lógica más parecida a esta:

```
case 1:
{
  int resp;
  do
  {
    int x;
    std::cout << "Ingrese elementos a la pila: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    pila.Apilar(x);
    std::cout << "\nSu numero apilado es " << x << '\n';

    std::cout << "Usted desea apilar algun otro numero? [SI = 0] [NO =1] ";
    std::cin >> resp;
  } while(resp==0);

  std::cout << "\nCarga de pila exitosa";
}
break;
```

Bonus finales:

Algunos consejos para hacerte a tí mismo la vida un poco más sencilla:

**no uses variables globales**

Tu programa no las necesita y lo único que pueden hacer ahora mismo es complicarte la vida. Acostúmbrate a usar variables locales.

La única excepción mientras aprendes sería en caso de que el usar variables globales sea una exigencia (absurda por otro lado) del ejercicio.

**C++ no es C (parte I): Las cabeceras no tienen extensión**

Las cabeceras de la librería estándar de C++ **no tienen extensión**. `iostream.h` puede que te funcione para un sistema en particular pero no esperes que la solución sea portable (puede no compilarte en casa o en clase... o incluso dejar de compilar si actualizas las librerías). Lo correcto es llamar a `iostream` a secas:

```
#include <iostream>
```

**C++ no es C (parte II): Las funciones sin argumentos no usan void**

En C cuando una función no necesita argumentos es necesario indicarlo con `void` porque si no el compilador entiende que admite un número arbitrario de argumentos. Sin embargo en C++ `void` es algo que vienen implícito.

Es preferile esto:

```
void menu()
```

A esto

```
void menu(void)
```

La excepción sería aquellos ficheros que vayan a hacer de interfaz con C, pero no creo que sea tu caso.

**C++ no es C (parte III): No es necesario usar `struct` cada dos por tres**

C++ es un lenguaje orientado a objetos. Una de las múltiples pruebas es que no hace falta usar `struct` nada más que a la hora de declarar un tipo:

```
struct nodo{ // <-- Aqui declaramos el tipo nodo
    int nro;
    nodo *sgte; // <-- Aqui ya no es necesario usar struct
};

typedef nodo* Puntero; // <-- Y aqui tampoco
```

Uno de los motivos por los que en C se usa tanto `typedef` es precisamente para no tener que usar `struct` en cada línea de código... en C++ no es tan común declarar alias para punteros... el código es sencillamente menos legible.

Es preferible esto:

```
class Pila{
    private:
        nodo* cima;
};
```

A esto:

```
class Pila{
    private:
        Puntero cima;
};
```

**C++ no es C (parte IV): new no es una función al uso**

Si bien existen usos más o menos retorcidos que justifican usos del tipo:

```
p_aux=new(struct nodo);
```

Lo normal es recurrir a una sintaxis mucho más amigable:

```
p_aux = new nodo; // Invoca el constructor por defecto

p_aux = new nodo(/* ... */); // Invoca un constructor específico
```

Y lo mismo es aplicable a `delete`:

```
delete p_aux; // No son necesarios los paréntesis.
```

**C++ no es C (parte V): no uses la interfaz de C**

En vista de tu código queda claro que sabes usar `cout` como sustituto de `printf` y lo mismo pasa con `cin`. Procura no mezclar `cin` y `cout` con `printf,`scanf` y compañía porque el resultado puede no ser de tu agrado:

- La sintaxis no es homogénea. `cin` y `cout` se basan en *streams*  propios de C++ mientras que `stdin` y `stdout` van por otro camino.
- Hay una función llamada `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio` que permite desincronizar los streams de C++ con los propios de C... si alguien llama a esa función y tu mezclas las llamadas prepárate para la diversión.
- Los *streams* de C++ facilitan crear funciones configurables (no tendrían por qué leer/escribir necesariamente de los dispositivos estándar), sin embargo al mezclar ambos sistemas se complica innecesariamente esta tarea (e incluso puede volverse inviable).
- Los *streams* de C++ son mucho más rápidos y potentes que lo heredado de C (le pese a quien le pese).

Mi consejo en este punto es que te acostumbres a usar `cin` y `cout` y a explorar todas sus posibilidades y reniegues de `printf` y `scanf` para casos muy justificados o para cuando programes en C.

**El menú no es coherente**

Tu menú solo tiene 5 opciones mientras que tu código está valorando 6 posibilidades... Se nota en que, por ejemplo, el menú dice que para *salir* es la opción *5* cuando el código asume que realmente es la opción *6*.

**No abuses de `system`**

`system` es totalmente dependiente del sistema operativo (además de lento). Como resulte que en clase te pongan una máquina linux para valorar tu ejercicio vas a suspender con toda seguridad... vale que las posibilidades de interacción con la consola son muy limitadas en C++... pero procura no tirar piedras sobre tu propio tejado.

**Hay que liberar la memoria**

En tu comando de salir no vacías la pila de forma manual... y la clase `Pila` no dispone de un destructor que sea capaz de liberar la memoria reservada por sus nodos.